# Client and REST API design: what does a REST Client consist of?

Tags: rest, api, client

Trying to wrap my head around the concept on how REST APIs and Web Client interact. Is the client itself basically a web application? I.e. the client itself has both a front end and a back end?

Comment: The client accesses endpoints defined by the REST API and displays the data provided by those endpoints.

Comment: So if for example I have a Spring REST API. What do I need as the client? Does the client itself need a back end (to consume the API?)

Comment: the rest api is considered the "backend".  The front end software is usually written in some sort of javascript library like react.js or angular etc.